# How to compute percentage change between corresponding elements in two dataframes r

Tags: r

I have two dataframes let's say A

```
col1    col2
  4       7
  5       8
```

and B

```
col1    col2
  2       5
  1       4
```

Now, I want to compute the percentage change between each corresponding element in the two dataframes. So, the percentage change between element 1,1 in A and B, between element 2,1 in A and B and so on. I want to store these percentage changes also in a 2 times 2 dataframe. Does anyone knows how to do this without looping over the dataframes?

Comment: Perhaps `(A-B)/A`   Please show your expected output

Comment: This indeed did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is true. I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these are equal-sized data.frames, simply do the subtraction and divide by one of the datasets would get the output

```
(A - B)/A
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use R element-wise matrix division.

If you do `A/B`, it will perform the division element by element. So, the complete formula for percentage would be `(A-B)/A`